# File compilation stuck

Tags: linux

I am about to lose my mind. Everytime I try to compile a simple latex document, compilation stucks at this step:

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathdesign/mdput/omlmdput.fd))

I am running Linux Mint 19 and have the texlive-full package installed. It does not matter if I compile the file as normal user or root.
Any ideas?

Comment: By commenting out various parts of your tex file, can you figure out which command is causing the problem?

Comment: this looks like it might be a loop from within a package.  you will have to dig through your log file to get an idea which one.  starting with the line you have shown, back up, ignoring everything that is completely enclosed by (parentheses) until you come to the last thing that *isn't* closed by a parenthesis.  that should give you the name of the package where the problem starts.  as soon as you have that information, you can come back here, add that information (maybe the log file from a line or two before that) to *this* question, and update.  that will give us more to work with.